# Standing Wave: Infinitely looping an MP3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

How do I infinitely loop an mp3 file in [standing wave](https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3). I've tried LoopSource with SoundGenerators etc, but I've had no luck. I can find no usage examples in the documentation or online of someone looping anInfinitely mp3:

```
var player:AudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer()
const generator:SoundGenerator = new SoundGenerator(sound)
source = new LoopSource(new AudioDescriptor(), generator)
player.play(source)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am the lib's author. Since a lot of people ask this question, I've added a page answering this question in the github wiki for the project.

https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3/wiki/How-to-use-loopsource

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @maxl0rd, I'm still having the same issue. I'm using the AudioPlayer to play the LoopSource, and it seems the audio player is somehow coming to the conclusion that the LoopSamples length is zero.

Comment: I have been trying to use the How-to-use-loopsource info. I am able to play my sound, but it only loops 3 times. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

it appears that the `LoopSource` function's `AudioDescriptor` parameter should match the `soundGenerator` parameter.  according to the docs instantiating a new `AudioDescriptor` will set the `channels` and `rate` properties as `NaN` (even though they're typed at `uint`??).  anyway, see if this works instead:

```
var player:AudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer()
const generator:SoundGenerator = new SoundGenerator(sound)
source = new LoopSource(generator.descriptor, generator)
player.play(source)
```

other than that, the `AudioPlayer` class contains a complete event, which is dispatched when the audio source has finished playing.  you could simply set up your own loop using a boolean switch to call `play(source:IAudioSource)` from the complete handler.

Comment: Hey @TheDarkIn1978, thanks for the effort, but no luck, I still only get one loop from this code.

Comment: try contacting the developer, maybe direct him to this question since there's a good change he's already a member on SO:  https://github.com/maxl0rd

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to use the How-to-use-loopsource info [here](https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3/wiki/How-to-use-loopsource). I am able to play my sound, but it only loops 3 times. Thoughts?

```
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.performance.ListPerformance;
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.elements.AudioDescriptor;
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.performance.AudioPerformer;
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.elements.IAudioSource;
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.sources.SineSource;
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.output.AudioPlayer;
import hype.framework.behavior.AbstractBehavior;
import com.greensock.loading.LoaderMax;
import com.greensock.loading.MP3Loader;
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.sources.LoopSource;
import com.noteflight.standingwave3.elements.Sample;
import flash.media.Sound;
import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
import com.demonsters.debugger.MonsterDebugger;
import flash.events.Event;


var player:AudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
var loader:LoaderMax = new LoaderMax( { onComplete:onComplete } );
loader.append( new MP3Loader( "../deploy/assets/audio/Letter_A1.mp3", { autoPlay:false } ) );
loader.load();


function onComplete(e:LoaderEvent):void
{

    var mySound:Sound = e.currentTarget.content[ 0 ] as Sound;
    var length:Number = mySound.length * 44.1;
    var mySample:com.noteflight.standingwave3.elements.Sample = new com.noteflight.standingwave3.elements.Sample( new AudioDescriptor, length );

    mySample.extractSound( mySound, 0, length ); // now all of the Sound's data is in this Sample

    // LoopSource
    var myLoop:LoopSource = new LoopSource( new AudioDescriptor( 44100, 2 ), mySample );
    myLoop.firstFrame = 1;
    myLoop.startFrame = 1;
    myLoop.endFrame = myLoop.frameCount;

    // Play.
    player.play( myLoop );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, since I was having a hell of a time trying to loop an audio source based on the documentation and a thin amount of help online, I decided to create my own Standing Wave 3 addons library. It's not perfect but it gets the job done, and on the byte level for that matter; No loop timers or anything. It works by taking in a Sound with beginning and ending loop points. Then it clones the loop sample a bunch of times based on the time provided in seconds. It should be straight forward to use. This is the code for the Main.as class in the 
"looping" file in the "examples" folder:

```
package
{

    // Imports.
    import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
    import com.greensock.loading.LoaderMax;
    import com.greensock.loading.MP3Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import com.greensock.TweenMax;
    import com.SW3.gadget.LoopGadget;
    import flash.media.Sound;


    // Class.
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        // Vars.
        private var loader:LoaderMax;// Using LoaderMax for ease of use.


        // Constructor.
        public function Main()
        {

            trace("Main");

            loader = new LoaderMax( { name:"audio", onComplete:onSoundsLoaded } );
            loader.append( new MP3Loader( "assets/Beat.mp3", { autoPlay:false } ) );
            loader.append( new MP3Loader( "assets/Clap.mp3", { autoPlay:false } ) );
            loader.append( new MP3Loader( "assets/Boom.mp3", { autoPlay:false } ) );
            loader.load();

        }


        private function onSoundsLoaded(e:LoaderEvent):void
        {

            trace("onSoundsLoaded");
            var looping:LoopGadget = new LoopGadget;
            looping.addLoopSound( "Beat", e.currentTarget.content[ 0 ] as Sound, 0, 10 );
            looping.addLoopSound( "Clap", e.currentTarget.content[ 1 ] as Sound, 0, 10 );
            //looping.addLoopSound( "Boom", e.currentTarget.content[ 2 ] as Sound, 0, 10 ); // Commented out to test possible error.

            looping.playLoop( "Beat" );// Play the "Beat" loop.
            looping.playLoop( "Clap" );// Play the "Clap" loop.
            looping.stopLoop( "Beat" );// Stop the "Beat" loop.
            looping.playLoop( "Beat" );// Play the "Beat" loop.
            looping.playLoop( "Beat" );// Play the "Beat" loop again to test if it would error out..

            looping.stopAllLoops();// Stop all the loops.
            looping.playLoops( [ "Beat", "Clap", "Boom" ] );// Play all the loops. Test to see if "Boom" will error out.

        }

    }

}
```

Check out the source files over here:
https://github.com/charlesclements/standingwave3-addons